# JAVAFX : Three tableviews => When i select a tableview, the others must be deleted and color removed

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I am a bit lost. In fact, i have three tableviews and i want to remove a selection from two of them when i click on a row which is in the third. In order to do that, i tried to remove selectionModel and focusModel. Nevertheless, the color remains and it is the problem

An example of the tried code is:

```
    private void initOnTableviewChange(TableView<PhrasePo> tableSelected, TableView<PhrasePo> table2, TableView<PhrasePo> table3) {
    tableSelected.selectionModelProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
        if (oldSelection == null) {

            if (table2.getSelectionModel() != null) {
                table2.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                table2.setSelectionModel(null);
            }

            if (table3.getSelectionModel() != null) {
                table3.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                table3.setSelectionModel(null);

            }
        }

    });

}
```

Please, can you help me to solve this problem.

Thank you for your help and i wish you a good day.

Cordially,

Vinz

Comment: I doubt that oldSelection becomes null. Put a debug statement there and check if it does

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Nevertheless, when a row is clicked, the others tableview must have lost there selection. Another point is when i arrive on the application. Nothing is selected.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: model the dependency in your data (vs some ad hoc wiring on the view side)

Comment: Why do you setSelectionModel to null? Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
private void initOnTableviewChange(TableView<PhrasePo> tableSelected, TableView<PhrasePo> table2, TableView<PhrasePo> table3) {
    tableSelected.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<PhrasePo> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            table2.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            table3.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

        });
        return row;
    });
```